# The golden ratio in java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Consider the sequence X1=1, X2= 1+1/1, X3= 1+1/1+1/1... . In this sequence Xn+1 = 1+1/Xn (for n>= 1). Write a method in Java that computes Xn. As n increases, the terms of this sequence get closer and closer to the golden ratio 1+sqrt 5/ 2 ~ 1.61803398875. How close is X10 to the golden ratio?

This is the program that I have written but when I run it in java it does not compile. I do not know what to do and it is due tomorrow. Please help!

```
public class Golden Ratio
```

{

```
public static final double GOLDEN = ( 1 + Math.sqrt(5))/2;
/**
 * precondition: Class(Golden Ratio), n values 
 * precondition: sequence values found
 */
public static double sequence (int n)
{
if (n == 0) {
return 1;
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
for (int n = 0; n < 40; n++)
{
double diff = Math.abs(sequence(n) - GOLDEN);
System.out.print(n+1+")");
System.out.print(n + 1 < 10 ? " seq " + sequence(n): "seq " + sequence (n))
System.out.print("gld " + GOLDEN);
System.out.print("diff = %.32f\t". diff);
System.out.print("\n");
}
System.out.print("\n");
System.out.print("10)" + "sqe " + sequence(9) + "ln gld + GOLDEN"\t diff = %.32 f\t" + diff);
System.out.print("");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the error message that the compiler gives you?

Comment: take the `main` method out of the `sequence` method, then call the `sequence` method from the `main` method.

Comment: That's what I had but when writing my program into this forum it would not let me post until I changed it.

Comment: The programs code. I may have just been a typo and I did not catch it until the forum asked me to change it.

Comment: @paulotorrens the message the complier gives me is that the main string method is the error.

Comment: A good first step is usually to type your error message into Google. At the very least you need to post the error message here. If the code you have isn't the code you tried to compile, there's no way for us to know what you did and didn't change, so we'd just be speculating as to what the problem is. If you're having trouble posting something to this site, [meta] would be the place to ask about that, at least after you read through [the editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: `public class Golden Ratio` will not compile. You're only allowed one identifier immediately following the keyword `class`. Check out the Java Tutorial.

Comment: @LewBloch so would i add in brackets to put the  2nd identifier out of the class?

Comment: I don't understand your question as phrased.

Comment: Why don't you TRY COMPILING IT YOURSELF?

Comment: That is what I am doing

Answer (score 0):

Your function should do all the calculating work.  Your main method just calls it and presents the results.  Here is how it's structured.  You'll still need to do the part that calculates the sequence.  Double-check the definition, before you do the work, though.  If X3=1 + 1/1 + 1/1, then that's the same as saying X3=3, which is obviously wrong.

```
public static double calculateSequence(int n) {
    double sum=0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
       // do your magic
    }
    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double answer=calculateSequence(10);
    System.out.println("%f is off by %f", answer, GOLDEN_RATIO - answer);
}
```